# Express routing not working when adding multiple placeholders

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I am studying node js, meanwhile I am facing this issue.

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

/*This route is working fine */
app.get("/:username", function (req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/ui/" + "user.html");
});

/*This route is not working */
app.get("/:username/:id", function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/ui/" + "user.html");
});
```

My folder Structure is

```
-server
  -public
    -ui 
        -ext (external files folder)
        - images(all images folder)
        -js (My js files folder)
        -style (my css folder)
        -user.html 
-index.js
-user.js
```

When I am trying to load url http://localhost:8888/stranger/19, my page is loading but none of the files specified in user.html is not loading. 
It seems like url of my css file is http://localhost:8888/stranger/ui/style/main.css instead of http://localhost:8888/ui/style/main.css.

This is happening for all files loading via ui. ("http://localhost:8888/stranger" this is coming instead of "http://localhost:8888"). How can I fix this issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/ext/bootstrap-3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/style/main.css" >

    <script src="ui/ext/jquery/jquery.min.js" ></script>   
    <script src="ui/ext/bootstrap-3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" i></script>
    <script src="ui/ext/moment.js" i></script>
    <script src="ui/js/main.js" ></script>
    <script src="ui/js/web.js" ></script>
    <script src="ui/js/user_module.js" ></script>
    <script src="ui/js/chat_module.js" ></script>

</head>
<body class="pz-main"> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Share your HTML file as well.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `route` to `static` file to `public directory`

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

[Here is the documentation on using the **public folder**](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Then in your html take the path as,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ui/style/main.css">
```

**Here are the working codes:**

your `app.js` or `server.js` where the `express` is defined

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get("/:username", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/ui/" + "user.html");
});

app.get("/:username/:id", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/ui/" + "user.html");
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
})
```

Your user.html in `public/ui` direcrtory.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ui/style/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    Page will be in green color due to css
  </body>
</html>
```

Your `css` in `public/ui/style` directory.

```
body{
  background: green; 
}
```

**Follow these steps and it will work.**

Comment: @user3037460, have you checked this? any help needed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `href` attribute.

Your current href attribute in `link` tag is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/ext/bootstrap-3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" >`

Which means to use current url as `base url`. Change it to following:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/ext/bootstrap-3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" >`

Simply add `/` at the start and it should fix the problem.